# Fences with non-atomics in C11

Tags: c11, memory-model, memory-fences

Is there any way to use fences to reason about the behavior of non-atomic operations in C11?  Specifically, I'd like to make code safe in situations where certain fields are required to be `int`s for compatibility with old interfaces that might, say, read and write data structures to files or pass them as system call arguments.  As there's no requirement that an `atomic_int` even be the same size as an `int`, I can't use an `atomic_int`.

Here's a minimal working example that unfortunately produces undefined behavior according to section 5.1.2.4 paragraph 25, because of the data race on `ready`:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>

int ready;  /* purposely NOT _Atomic */
int value;

void
p1()
{
  value = 1;
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
  ready = 1;
}

void
p2(void *_ignored)
{
  while (!ready)
    ;
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
  printf("%d\n", value);
}

int
main()
{
  thrd_t t;
  thrd_create(&t, p2, NULL);
  p1();
  thrd_join(&t, NULL);
}
```

My specific question is whether it's possible to fix the above code to guarantee printing `1` without changing `ready` to an `_Atomic`.  (I could make `ready` a `volatile`, but don't see any suggestion in the spec that this would help.)

A related question is whether it's safe to write the above code anyway, because any machine my code will run on has cache coherence?  I'm aware that [many](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) [things](http://www.usenix.org/event/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf) go [wrong](http://erdani.com/publications/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) when C11 programs contain so-called benign races, so I'm really looking for the specifics of what a plausible compiler and architecture could do to the above code rather than general warnings about data races and undefined behavior.

Comment: All synchronization operations in C11 only work on atomics (or `mtx_t`). So without any atomic this can never work. Once you have an atomic of which you control the state, you can argue with the happens-before relation which effects become visible in which thread, even for effects on non-atomci objects. **But** making your things "compatible" with old interfaces is hopeless with C11 atomics. They are not made for this. Allowing these old interfaces act non-atomically on the state of your system punches holes in any proof of consistency  that you might come up with.

Comment: @JensGustedt To be clear, though, my question was about fences, not atomics.  Fences do constrain the ordering of non-atomic memory operations.  In this particular example, the release fence happens before the acquire fence, so there is no race on `value`, just on `ready`.  So maybe the answer is to use `memory_order_acq_rel` in both cases?

Comment: No, I think you have the wrong idea about this. Two fences in different threads only synchronize via an atomic. There is no other way to argue that one fence happens before another without having modified an atomic object which modification is perceived by the other.

Comment: @JensGustedt: If one has code that calls a function to populate a buffer and then does some action to indicate that it should be used asynchronously, is there any practical way to make such code workable without having to use a special "atomic" version of the function that fills the buffer or add an extra "atomic copy" step?  If not, that would seem a rather senseless omission in the Standard.

Comment: @supercat, I am not sure that I understand your question completely. Fact is, that you can't impose synchronization behavior for a function that doesn't specify anything about it. The function might have been compiled before C11 even existed. That said, the classical way to deal with legacy code in a parallel setting is to put mutexes around their usage. That is always guaranteed to synchronize. Parallelization always has a cost, there is no miraculous finger snipping that makes an existing code (= written without any atomic or lock primitive) parallel and free of races.

Comment: @JensGustedt: On many embedded implementations, volatile accesses behave as global write fences.  This makes it practical to call a function which populates a buffer and then uses a volatile write to trigger some asynchronous process that reads out the buffer.  If the function which populated the buffer used volatile writes, they would naturally be ordered with respect to the action which triggers the asynchronous readout, but in many cases having groups of operations which are asynchronous relative to each other operations in the same group but globally sequenced relative to other groups...

Comment: @supercat, I also didn't say that all the data  must be written atomically. There must be an atomic write that comes after the one fence that is visible in the other thread. Only by seeing such an event, you can deduce that your acquire fence is actually happing after the release fence. Otherwise there is no way to establish a temporal or causal order.

Comment: ...would allow many more useful optimizations than would using `volatile` on everything that needs to respect any sort of sequencing at all.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Most embedded-system stuff uses asynchronous mechanisms other than threads, but from a threading standpoint, if #1 does some ordinary writes, then some kind of write fence and a volatile write, and #2 does a volatile  read which sees that the volatile write has occurred, then some kind of read fence followed by ordinary reads, is there any kind of fence that would assure sequencing between the ordinary writes and the ordinary reads.

Comment: It just has to do an atomic (volatile is not sufficient) write after the fence, and the other thread has to ensure that he atomically reads that written value. Volatile only guarantees that the write cannot be optimized out, it enforces nothing about inter-thread synchronization.

Comment: I wonder if a reasonable thing to do is to use `atomic_int` if `sizeof(atomic_int) == sizeof(int)`, and otherwise use a volatile (figuring that you are on some archaic single-core architecture)?  Can you cast between `int *` and `atomic_int *` if they are the same size?

Comment: @JensGustedt: Would the atomic write after the fence prevent a compiler from deferring any "ordinary" writes from before the fence to a point after it?  Any implementation should be able to implement an operation whose behavior was equivalent to calling a variadic outside function the compiler knows nothing about, but which doesn't actually do anything.  A compiler would not be able to register-cache anything reachable by any pointer that had ever been passed to such a function, thus achieving necessary semantics.

Comment: The problem is not if the compiler can reorder writes before the fence with the fence. It can't because of the usual sequency rules. The problem is a problem of visibility of the fence  in the other thread. The fence is only guaranteed to be visible if there is an established dependency chain between the release fence in the first and the acquire fence in the second. If there is no dependency the execution can pretend that the release fence didn't happen, yet. Such an dependency can only be established by a synchronization operation, here an atomic write that is knowingly read by the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to use fences to reason about the behavior of non-atomic operations in C11?

The way you use fences is correct but if you want to be able to reason about program behavior,
it is your responsibility to ensure that there is a strict inter-thread modification order between the store(1) to `ready`
and the load(1) from it. This is normally where an `atomic` variable comes into play.
Per the C11 standard you have a data race on `ready` (as you pointed out) and undefined behavior is what you can expect.

> My specific question is whether it's possible to fix the above code to guarantee printing 1 without changing ready to an _Atomic.
>    (I could make ready a volatile, but don't see any suggestion in the spec that this would help.)

The standards conforming answer is 'no' and since the standard does not support your case you won't find anything related to `volatile` in this context.

However, the standard is strict on purpose considering that one of the goals is to support compatibility with many architectures.
That does not mean that a data race will always lead to problems on each platform.

The issues with using non-atomic types in a shared context are tricky though.
People sometimes believe that if CPU operations on a type such as `int` are indivisible, it can be used as a substitute for `atomic_int`.
This is not true because 'atomic' is a concept with wider ramifications:

- indivisible read/writes - These apply to regular types on many platforms.
- restricted optimizations - Compiler transformations can truly cause undefined behavior in many unexpected ways.
  A compiler may re-order memory operations, combine a variable with another in the same memory location,
  remove a variable from a loop, keep it in a register, etc...
  You can prevent much of this by declaring your variable `volatile` as it puts restrictions on what the compiler can do wrt optimizations.
- data synchronization between cores - in your case, this is handled by the fences under the condition that there is a strict inter-thread ordering on `ready` between the store and the load.
  With a real `atomic_int`, you could have used relaxed operations.

Whether your code works, depends on platform and compiler, but at least declare the `ready` flag `volatile`.
I did a test run on X86_64 with `gcc -O3` compiler optimization and without `volatile` it was caught in an endless loop.
It is also a good idea to compare the difference between compiler emitted instructions for the atomic and non-atomic case.

> A related question is whether it's safe to write the above code anyway, because any machine my code will run on has cache coherence?

You definitely want cache-coherency because systems that do not support it are notoriously hard to program. The way you wrote it will almost certainly not work without cache-coherency.