# Can atomic_thread_fence(acquire) prevent previous loads being reordered after itself?

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I understand `atomic_thread_fence` in C++ is quite different with atomic store/loads, and it is not a good practice to understand them by trying to interpret them into CPU(maybe x86)'s mfence/lfence/sfence.

If I use `c.load(memory_order_acquire)`, no stores/loads after `c.load` can be reordered before `c.load`. However, I think there are no restriction to stores/loads before `c.load`. I mean some stores/loads before `c.load` can be reordered after it theoretically.

However when it comes to `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire)`, it involves 3 kinds of objects: the fence, store/loads before this fence and store/loads after this fence.

I think the fence will certainly prevent store/loads after this fence being reordered before itself, just like atomic store/load. But will it prevent store/loads before this fence being reordered after itself?

I think the answer is yes with the following searching:

1. In [preshing's article](https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/)

   > An acquire fence prevents the memory reordering of any read which precedes it in program order with any read or write which follows it in program order.

   So he does not specify a direction.
2. In [modernescpp](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/acquire-release-fences)

   > there is an additional guarantee with the acquire memory barrier. No read operation can be moved after the acquire memory barrier.

   So I think he say yes directly?

However, I find no "official" answer in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence), it only specifies how fences and atomics interact with each other in different threads.

but I am not sure, so I have this question.

Comment: I think the information on cppreference.com is complete. It describes all the _synchronizes-with_ relations fences generate with other atomic operations. This _synchronizes-with_ relation transitively extends the _sequenced-before_ relation in the individual threads to the _happens-before_ relation of all memory operations.

Comment: @user17732522 How about non-atomic operations?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Inter-thread_happens-before, e.g. if atomic operation A _synchronizes-with_ an atomic operation X, and X is _sequenced-before_ a (non-atomic) operation B (in the same thread as X), then A _happens-before_ X. (and so on, transitively extended to all operations, whether atomic or not)

Comment: @user17732522 It may be also off topic, so if there are no atomic objects, there are no way(even with difference kinds of fences provided by C++ standard), that we can establish order among variables in other threads. However, we can still do that with outside C++ standards, like we all did before C++11. i.e using `asm volatile("" ::: "memory")`, or some methods provided by Linux?

Comment: You're right that x86 sfence/lfence are useless for understanding `atomic_thread_fence`, since those instructions are no-ops as far as memory ordering unless you've been using NT stores (to any location), or SSE4.1 MOVNTDQA loads from video RAM or other WC memory.  But yes, more generally, for a weakly-ordered ISA like ARM64 that does need a barrier to block LoadLoad+LoadStore for an `atomic_thread_fence(acquire)`, it doesn't answer the question of whether ISO C++ really requires that it separate non-atomic loads on one side from non-atomic loads on the other side.

Comment: In asm, the model is based on whether loads from coherent shared cache are locally reordered or not, and that's always meaningful; there's no such thing as a "non-atomic" load; that C++ concept allows the compiler to maybe not even actually emit a load or store instruction at all.  So yeah, anything you real in terms of actual asm barrier instructions will just talk about blocking all loads from reordering across it in either direction.

Comment: After reading your question more carefully, looks like your modernescpp link is making the same mistake that Preshing debunked in https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/ - **fences are 2-way barriers**, otherwise they'd be useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question more carefully, looks like your modernescpp link is making the same mistake that Preshing debunked in https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/ - **fences are 2-way barriers**, otherwise they'd be useless.

A relaxed load followed by an acquire fence is at least as strong as an acquire load.  Anything in this thread after the acquire fence happens after the load, thus it can synchronize-with a release store (or a release fence + relaxed store) in another thread.

> But will it prevent store/loads before this fence being reordered after itself?

Stores no, it's only an acquire fence.

Loads, yes.  In terms of a memory model where there is coherent shared cache/memory, and we're limiting local reordering of access to that, an acquire fence blocks LoadLoad and LoadStore reordering.  https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/

(This is *not* the way ISO C++'s formalism defines things.  It works in terms of happens-before rules that order things relative to a load that saw a value from a store.  In those terms, a relaxed load followed by an acquire fence can create a happens-before relationship with a release-sequence, so later code in this thread sees everything that happened before the store in the other thread.)

Comment: My understanding is acquire/release fence should be used in pair. And there will be the following order: `non-atomic/relaxed before acquire -> acquire -> release -> non-atomic/relaxed after release`?

Comment: @calvin: Yes, but not in the same thread; to simulate an acquire operation using fences and relaxed ops, you only need one fence in the reading thread.  The point of load ordering is to sync with store ordering.  But if the acquire fence was only a 1-way barrier, it wouldn't be sufficient to keep 2 loads on opposite sides of itself, and not work as the acquire side of a synchronization.  Updated my answer.

Comment: (IDK why you have one big `code block` in your comment; maybe that's supposed to be two threads? Not clear what point you're making; a release store has to happen before an acquire load for the load to see it and thus create a happens-before relationship.)

Comment: So, "acquire fence prevents LoadLoad and LoadStore" is not a definition, but a consequence we can infer from definition.  But I think I am not fully understand what   a "prevents LoadStore" means. For example, if we have a `R1 (acquire fence) W2`, I think the following reorder is not permitted: `W2 R1 (acquire fence)`/`W2 (acquire fence) R1`/`(acquire fence) W2 R1`(correct me if I am wrong). However, can the following reorder valid `R1 W2 (aquire fence)`/`(aquire fence) R1 W2`?

Comment: @calvin: It's a definition if you're thinking in terms of reordering operations in one thread, rather than in terms of C++ formalism.  The ISO standard doesn't talk about "reordering", it talks about "happens before", and the formal definition of that restricts what values a load is allowed to see.  Anyway, you *are* wrong.  `R1 acq_fence W2` can't reorder at all relative to each other.  All loads have to stay on their initial side of the fence, and later stores have to stay later.  (An earlier store separate from R1 and W2 could reorder past that whole sequence, though, since it's not SC.)

Comment: @calvin: Did you read https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/ ?  It's about C++11 fences, and pretty much answers your question; my answer here was mostly just a placeholder, enough to not be a link-only answer, because it's already well-answered by that article.

Comment: I actually read this article, and have seen "but a release fence must prevent preceding memory operations from being reordered past all subsequent writes", but I think he only says "no preceding load/store can be reordered past release fence". I want to make sure that "stores after release fence can't be reordered before release fence", which I have not found from this article.

Comment: @calvin: stores can't cross a release fence in either direction.  It includes a StoreStore barrier.  https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/ which you linked in the question shows that in a diagram, and says so in text.  That's also a necessary consequence of the cppreference page which says "*In this case, all non-atomic and relaxed atomic stores that are sequenced-before FA in thread A will happen-before all non-atomic and relaxed atomic loads from the same locations made in thread B after FB*".  Wouldn't be possible if any ops before a release fence could cross it.

Comment: @calvin:  ​I searched within the page for the text you quoted in double-quotes, but didn't find it in either of Jeff Preshing's articles, so maybe you're paraphrasing.

Comment: Here is the link https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/#:~:text=but%20a%20release%20fence%20(such%20as%20the%20one%20on%20the%20right)%20must%20prevent%20preceding%20memory%20operations%20from%20being%20reordered%20past%20all%20subsequent%20writes

Comment: @calvin: ok, found it.  Yeah, notice that stopping earlier loads/stores from reordering with "all subsequent writes" can only happen if the barrier itself stays between them, i.e. not itself reordering with later writes, that's the whole point. (Or has some magical effect on every later write, and then disappears.)  It's just an alternate way of stating the same thing he already stated in [his earlier article](https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/) on fences which you linked.

Comment: OK, so if what I only need is to prevent all Load-Load(e.g.) reordering between all non-atomic/atomic variables **in a single thread**, rather than establishing synchronizes-with relationship between some atomic variables inter-threads, can I use `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire)` alone? In my view, it is a enhanced `atomic_signal_fence` that also prevents reorder by CPU.

Comment: @calvin: In practice yes.  In theory no, because if it's not actually syncing with anything then the as-if rule allows a hypothetical compiler to optimize away behaviour that's not observable in a UB-free program.  But real compilers don't optimize atomics, and will emit a fence on the spot.  SO has Q&As about that, like [Fences in C++0x, guarantees just on atomics or memory in general](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5547212) / [Fences with non-atomics in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42122610)

Comment: Do you mean if `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire)` is not used to establish synchronize-with relationship, it then has no "observable behavior". It conforms to C++ standard if we optimize away this fence, just like we optimize away a infinite loop that does nothing. However, real compilers choose not to do so?

Comment: @calvin: Yeah, pretty much.  Not just that they "choose not" to optimize this way, more like it would be extremely hard to be sure there were no possible observers.  And the compiler doesn't have a complete view of what happened before or after in this thread, just in the current function after inlining, so it couldn't prove there are no later atomic operations.  (Actually even exiting a thread has release semantics)